# Weird output on C program

Tags: c

I was tasked with created a program that pulls inputs from the CL and works with them

It should do the following

Input ./name Test + Best + Rest
Output TestBestRest

Input ./name 600 + 500 - 100
Output 1000

Words will only ever be concatenated to the string, but numbers must be able to be added or subtracted. In a mixed string everything is considered a string not an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char arr1[15][25]={'\0'};
    int nums=0;
    int temp;
    char tempstring[15]={'\0'};
    char symbol[15]={'\0'};
    int tempnum=0;
    int endnum=0;
    char strcat[100]={'\0'};

    printf("This program only recognizes 10 command line entries\n");

    for(int indx=1;indx<argc;indx+=1)
    {
        char *input = argv[indx];
//      if(isalnum(input[indx]))
            strncpy(tempstring,argv[indx],14);
        if (indx>1)
            strncpy(symbol,argv[indx-1],14);
        printf("index is %d\n",indx);
            printf("Tempstring is %s\n\n",tempstring);
        tempnum=atoi(tempstring);
            printf("Tempnum is %d\n",tempnum);
        if(tempnum!=0)
        {
            printf("inside %d\n", indx);

            printf("Temp num %d and End num is %d\n", tempnum,endnum);
//          printf("is num\n");
            printf("Tempstring is %s\n\n",tempstring);
            printf("Tempnum is %d\n",tempnum);
            printf("symbol is %c\n\n",symbol[0]);

            if (symbol[0]==45)
            {
                endnum=endnum-tempnum;
                printf("minus\n");
            }
            else if(symbol[0]==43)
            {
                printf("plus\n");
                endnum=endnum+tempnum;
            }else if (indx==1)
            {
                printf("no sym\n");
                endnum=endnum+tempnum;
            }
        }

        if (isalpha(input[indx])!=0)
        {
            printf("argv[%d] = %s\n",indx, tempstring);
            //strncpy(arr1[indx],argv[indx],10);
            if (tempstring[0]!=43)
                strncat(strcat,tempstring,14);
        }

    }
        printf("End number %d\n",endnum);
    printf("Concatenated %s\n", strcat);

    return 0;
}
```

The code does what is asked (I am sorry for the error checking printfs) with one exception

If you enter ./name Test + Rest + Best + 600
It outputs TestRest600.

This is what the code results with the printfs

```
─╼ $./a6p1 Test + Rest + Best + 600
This program only recognizes 10 command line entries
index is 1
Tempstring is Test

Tempnum is 0
argv[1] = Test
index is 2
Tempstring is +

Tempnum is 0
argv[2] = +
index is 3
Tempstring is Rest

Tempnum is 0
argv[3] = Rest
index is 4
Tempstring is +

Tempnum is 0
argv[4] = +
index is 5
Tempstring is Best

Tempnum is 0
index is 6
Tempstring is +

Tempnum is 0
argv[6] = +
index is 7
Tempstring is 600

Tempnum is 600
inside 7
Temp num 600 and End num is 0
Tempstring is 600

Tempnum is 600
symbol is +

plus
argv[7] = 600
End number 600
Concatenated TestRest600
```

any assistance would be most welcome, I am aware its got some junk code that I need to clean up on a second pass but I was hoping to figure this out first.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the arguments?

Comment: You should really use character literals (e.g. `+`) instead of integer constants like 43.

Comment: assignment instructions, its silly but it must be done. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks for the tip, i appreciate it. I was having a problem with that when comparing to string.

Comment: I intended to say "character literals (e.g. `'+'` -- note the single quotes)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the line:

```
if (isalpha(input[indx])!=0)
```

The variable `indx` is used to index the arguments to the program, and here you use it to index the characters within the argument, which is a very bad idea. For the argument `Best` index is equal to `5` and accessing "Best"[5] will give you a '\0', which is a string terminator, and not a letter, which is why `Best` is not concatenated.

You should probably use this instead:

```
if (isalpha(input[0])!=0)
```